# Extending line features to another line features with same attribute value using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, contour, extend

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have received a set of contour lines from a third-party person. After analyzing the polyline data, I have seen a bunch of contour lines having a gap between other contour lines with the same attribute value (Z-value).

Are there any tools such as Snap/Extend tool to extend the line to another line with the same Z-Value?

[image]

Comment: That's more than a little tricky. Is the "correct" line as you've drawn it, or by making a single turn where the extended line segments would intercept?

Comment: I just need to make the line intercept each other between polylines with the same z-value attribute. So just need to make a single turn where the extended line segments would intercept, or a straight line to each polyline vertex. No accuracy is needed for the extended line area as they ask me to clean and repair the gap

Comment: I doubt you'll find a pre-built tool to make such a risky "no accuracy" modification. The task itself  could be under 100 lines of ArcPy. Why not give it a shot?